# How can I use DNS-prefetch on Leaflet map tile providers?

Tags: dns, leaflet, cross-domain, subdomain, prefetch

I am using several map tile providers in a Leaflet map and want to use DNS prefetch on the map tile layers providers/sites to reduce the page load time. But it is confusing as the the URLs of these sites use different subdomains in the format: `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/` like `a.tile.openstreetmap.org` and `b.tile.openstreetmap.org`.

```
var mapnik = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: "&copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a>"
});
var stamenT = L.tileLayer("https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: "Map tiles by <a href='https://stamen.com'>Stamen Design</a>, <a href='https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0'>CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a>",
    subdomains: "abcd"
});
```

How should I be able to use the DNS prefetch for these external resources. Do I have to use `link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect"` for each subdomain, or do I have to use only one for a single domain (like using only:

> `<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://openstreetmap.org">`

instead of:

> `<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org">`
>   `<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org">`

and so on).

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` on every subdomain as DNS has no inherent knowledge of what constitutes a domain and a subdomain. It would be interesting to see what difference it makes.

Comment: True but that part "DNS has no inherent knowledge of what constitutes a domain and a subdomain." not so true. A nameserver has to know about zone cuts to handle DNSSEC validation properly and QNAME minimization. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7816 and its Appendix A: "This algorithm performs name resolution with QNAME minimisation in the presence of zone cuts that are not yet known.". See also definition in RFC2181: The
   existence of a zone cut is indicated in the parent zone by the
   existence of NS records specifying the origin of the child zone.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Fair comment, I didn't think that through. Thanks for the correction. I don't think it impacts the question in hand, though.